# Exception calling "Demand" with "0" argument(s): "Request for principal permission failed."

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-2.0

From the following block of PS

```
$myAppDomain = [System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain
$myPrincipal = [System.Security.Principal.PrincipalPolicy]::WindowsPrincipal
$myAppDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy($myPrincipal)
$myPrincipalPermission = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Permissions.PrincipalPermission -ArgumentList $null, "Administrators"
$myPrincipalPermission.Demand()
```

I am getting the following exception.

```
Exception calling "Demand" with "0" argument(s): "Request for principal
permission failed."
At line:1 char:30
+ $myPrincipalPermission.Demand <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

The version of PowerShell is

```
$PSVersionTable
Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.8762
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

I wrote the script based on the [`PrincipalPermission` class documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.principalpermission(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Funky. I can reproduce the issue (and work around it by supplying the current username), but [looking at the source, nothing seems to explain why](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/permissions/principalpermission.cs,461)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Simplified version that will work where the logged in user is explicitly a member of the Windows Group "Users".

```
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy([System.Security.Principal.PrincipalPolicy]::WindowsPrincipal)
$myCP = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentPrincipal
$myPP = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Permissions.PrincipalPermission -ArgumentList $myCP.Identity.Name, "Users"
$myPP.Demand()
```

If no SecurityException is raised, Demand succeeds. Reference 
[PrincipalPermission.Demand Method () Remarks](http://%22https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.principalpermission.demand(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2)